# (SPARQL) BIND fails with values from nested query

Tags: sparql, bind, subquery

I have been having problems with BIND IF in nested query (SPARQL). BIND fails and returns empty column (*?koordColor*) if I try to evaluate and bind value from inner query *?pop20* and *?pop14-?pop20* but is successful if I evaluate and bind *?pop14*. Does anyone know how to fix this query so that I could evaluate and bind according to *?pop14-?pop20* value successfully?

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX qb: <http://purl.org/linked-data/cube#>
PREFIX lvcsb: <http://127.0.0.1:8080/LOD/>
PREFIX lvcsb-geo: <http://127.0.0.1:8080/LOD/territory/>
prefix opengis: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>
prefix lvl:    <http://127.0.0.1:8080/LOD/statLevel/>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
  
SELECT  ?label ?koordColor ?koord ?pop20 ?pop14 
WHERE {
        ?obs a qb:Observation.
        ?obs lvcsb:refPeriod 2014.
        ?obs lvcsb:refArea ?area.
        ?area lvcsb:version ?ver.
        ?ver rdfs:label ?label.
        ?ver opengis:Geometry ?geo.
        ?geo opengis:asWKT ?koord.
        ?obs lvcsb:population ?pop14.
        BIND(IF(?pop14-?pop20 > 1000, "green", "blue") AS ?koordColor)
        {SELECT ?label ?pop20 WHERE {
            ?obs a qb:Observation.
            ?obs lvcsb:refPeriod 2020.
            ?obs lvcsb:refArea ?area.
            ?area lvcsb:version ?ver.
            ?ver rdfs:label ?label.
            ?obs lvcsb:population ?pop20.
            {SELECT distinct ?label where{
                ?obs a qb:Observation.
                ?obs lvcsb:refArea ?area.
                ?area lvcsb:version ?ver.
                ?ver rdfs:label ?label .
                ?ver   lvcsb:statLevel  ?level .
                filter(?level = lvl:4 )
                filter(lang(?label)='lv')}
            }}
}}
```

Comment: put the `BIND` after the subquery